# the order of code execution with if statment and ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

please take a look at my code, I don't understand why ajax call is fired up even I returned false.

```
if (isValidationSelected(SaveMapperViewModel)) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/admin/import/validation',
        data: JSON.stringify(SaveMapperViewModel),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        success: function (response) {
            // do something 
        },
    });
} else {
        console.log(`test`);
    // do something 
}

function isValidationSelected(SaveMapperViewModel) {
    // do something 
    if (result.length != 0) {
        // do something 
        alert(msg);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have a dot in the controller for debug (ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC). When `isValidationSelected` return false, debug go to controller and at the same time I have msg in browser console from `console.log` - `test`. For testing purpose I change code like this:

```
isValidationSelected(SaveMapperViewModel).done(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/admin/import/validation',
        data: JSON.stringify(SaveMapperViewModel),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        success: function (response) {
            //do somoething
        },
    });
});

isValidationSelected(SaveMapperViewModel).fail(function () {
    console.log('test 2');
});

function isValidationSelected(SaveMapperViewModel) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    //do something
    if (result.length != 0) {
        //do something
        alert(msg);
        deferred.fail();
    } else {
        deferred.resolve();
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

debug behaves the same as in the first case.

What I'm missing? I suppose it's about the asynchrony of javascript, but in this case the code behaves incomprehensibly for me. I guess I just don't know something.

My aim is to fire up `ajax` call only when I return true from `isValidationSelected`.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
For testing purpose I change code like that, and still I'm showing `alert(msg)` and the ajax is fired up. Due to the question below what is doing `//do something` I paste all the nesesery code.

```
    $('#startImport').on('click', function () {
        var SaveMapperViewModel = createObj(),
            result = [];

        for (var o in SaveMapperViewModel.Pairs) {
            var row = SaveMapperViewModel.Pairs[o];
            if (row.Validation == 0) {
                result.push(row);
            }
        }

        if (result.length != 0) {
            var msg = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var row = result[i];
                msg += '"' + row.Value + '" + "' + row.ColOrRow + '" - proszę wybrać rodzaj walidacji \n';
            }

            alert(msg);
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/admin/import/validation',
                data: JSON.stringify(SaveMapperViewModel),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response) {

                    } else {
                        errors += "success- ImportMapper start import";
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    errors += "error - ImportMapper start import";
                },
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your `isValidationSelected` function doesn't make any sense...you should return true or false based on the `SaveMapperViewModel` parameter or not?

Comment: Is `// do something` inside `isValidationSelected` some kind of anynchronous operation? Because you said the control reaches `else` part and the controller debugger is being triggered.

Comment: @Hackerman - isValidationSelected - has to return false when a few loops find something and show msg alert, but where every thing is valid should return true
@adiga `some kind of anynchronous operation` - no there are: a classic `for`, `push` to table and `for in`, `msg` is a string variable

Comment: certainly looks like your function being called more than once. set up a minimal reproducible case in jsfiddle

Comment: hahahaha but pathetic and found the second `$ ('# startImport'). on ('click', function () {...`